# What is causing this white line between the top banner and navigation and how to remove it?

Tags: html

The code for this is located at this link. It is generated using a template and data. I have tried using several things, like firebug and dragonfly in Opera.

http://archives.subscribermail.com/msg/87a4a85001714fa385b5eb6f30de375e.htm

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] to see how and what to ask here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a style with `display: block` to banner img

Comment: perfect - i was able to correct the problem - thank you for your help!